# HTTPS POST using HttpClient API opening 2 sockets

Tags: java, networking, https

After a lot of R&D and googling, not able to troubleshoot my problem.

**Environment Setup**

Web Server (Tomcat 6.0.20) --> Proxy Server (Windows Server 2007) --> Thirdy part host

We have application, which does online payment transaction, after completion of this transaction, we want to send status of transaction to third party server. So posting data to third part server from our web server is opening 2 sockets for one transaction at proxy server, but when we check at web server it has created only one socket. SO why 2 socket at proxy server.

Below is my sample code

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.*;


public class HTTPPostDemo {

    private String privateKey;
    private String host;
    private int port;
    private String userName;
    private Header[] headers = null;

    public class MySSLSocketFactory implements SecureProtocolSocketFactory {

        private TrustManager[] getTrustManager() {
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
            };
            return trustAllCerts;
        }

        public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {

            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = getTrustManager();
            try {
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
                SocketFactory socketFactory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
                return socketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new UnknownHostException("Problems to connect " + host + ex.toString());
            }
        }

        public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean flag) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = getTrustManager();
            try {

                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
                SocketFactory socketFactory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
                return socketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new UnknownHostException("Problems to connect " + host + ex.toString());
            }

        }

        public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress clientHost, int clientPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {

            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = getTrustManager();
            try {
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
                SocketFactory socketFactory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
                return socketFactory.createSocket(host, port, clientHost, clientPort);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new UnknownHostException("Problems to connect " + host + ex.toString());
            }

        }
    }

    public SslClient(String host, int port, String userName, String privateKey) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.privateKey = privateKey;
    }

    protected String md5Sum(String str) {
        String sum = new String();
        try {
            MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            sum = String.format("%032x", new BigInteger(1, md5.digest(str.getBytes())));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return sum;

    }

    public String getSignature(String xml) {
        return md5Sum(md5Sum(xml + privateKey) + privateKey);
    }

    public String sendRequest(String xml) throws Exception {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.setConnectionTimeout(60000);
        client.setTimeout(60000);
        String response = new String();
        String portStr = String.valueOf(port);
        Protocol.registerProtocol("https", new Protocol("https", new MySSLSocketFactory(), port));
        String signature = getSignature(xml);
        String uri = "https://" + host + ":" + portStr + "/";
        PostMethod postRequest = new PostMethod(uri);
        postRequest.addRequestHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(xml.length()));
        postRequest.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        postRequest.addRequestHeader("X-Signature", signature);
        postRequest.addRequestHeader("X-Username", userName);
        postRequest.setRequestBody(xml);
        System.out.println("Sending https request....." + postRequest.toString());

        try {
            client.executeMethod(postRequest);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new TaskExecuteException("Sending post got exception ", ex);
        }

        response = postRequest.getResponseBodyAsString();
        headers = postRequest.getRequestHeaders();
        return response;
    }

    public String getPrivateKey() {
        return privateKey;
    }

    public void setPrivateKey(String privateKey) {
        this.privateKey = privateKey;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Header[] getHeaders() {
        return headers;
    }

    public void setHeaders(Header[] headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String privateKey = "your_private_key";
        String userName = "your_user_name";
        String host = "demo.site.net";
        int port = 55443;

        String xml =
                "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no' ?>"
                + "<!DOCTYPE OPS_envelope SYSTEM 'ops.dtd'>"
                + "<OPS_envelope>"
                + "<header>"
                + "<version>0.9</version>"
                + "<msg_id>2.21765911726198</msg_id>"
                + "<msg_type>standard</msg_type>"
                + "</header>"
                + "<body>"
                + "<data_block>"
                + "<dt_assoc>"
                + "<item key='attributes'>"
                + "<dt_assoc>"
                + "<item key='domain'>test-1061911771844.com</item>"
                + "<item key='pre-reg'>0</item>"
                + "</dt_assoc>"
                + "</item>"
                + "<item key='object'>DOMAIN</item>"
                + "<item key='action'>LOOKUP</item>"
                + "<item key='protocol'>XCP</item>"
                + "</dt_assoc>"
                + "</data_block>"
                + "</body>"
                + "</OPS_envelope>";

        SslClient sslclient = new SslClient(host, port, userName, privateKey);

        try {
            String response = sslclient.sendRequest(xml);
            System.out.println("\nResponse is:\n" + response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

As in a day we are processing 10,000 + transactions, so number of socket at proxy are getting increased, so after 2-3 days, we need to do hard reboot of web server to free all the open sockets with proxy server.

Does HTTPClient, opens one socket for SSL Handshake and another for actual data post ? I don't think so. Then it should be at Web server and not at Proxy Server

For checking sockets and open ports at web server we are using netstat command.
For checking sockets and open ports at proxy server we are using proxy tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When socket ports run out, transaction timeouts occur. The solution to this problem is to tune the TIMEWAIT-related Windows registry parameters:

- TcpTimedWaitDelay
- MaxUserPort
- StrictTimeWaitSeqCheck

The TIMEWAIT-related Windows registry parameters control how long a socket port remains unavailable after it is closed and how many ports are available for use.

By setting these windows registry parameters, I have solved this problem, but don't know, weather it is a correct solution to implement or not.

Answer (score 0):

> when we check at web server it has created only one socket.

Because there is only one inbound connection to it.

> SO why 2 socket at proxy server.

Because you are connecting to two different servers via the proxy server?

> number of socket at proxy are getting increased, so after 2-3 days, we need to do hard reboot of web server to free all the open sockets with proxy server.

That doesn't make sense. It's the proxy server that has the dual connections, not the web server. You said that above. If the web server is running out of sockets, somebody isn't closing their connections correctly: the client, the proxy server, or the web server. Possibly your socket factory needs to override equals() and maybe hashCode() too, to enable whatever connection pooling `HttpClient` may do, I'm not an expert on that.

**BUT** your `TrustManager` is radically insecure. If you have this deployed in production, you have already committed a *major* security breach. This is currently a *much* bigger problem that running out of sockets every few days.

Comment: Above code is not the production code fully. We are closing all sockets and input, output streams, other connection variables, in finally block. So i dont thing its the code problem. How can we free open sockets at OS layer ?

Comment: @RahulAgrawal Clearly you aren't. Clearly there is a socket leak somewhere. There is no such thing as freeing open sockets at the OS later. That's what `Socket.close()` is for.

Comment: socket.close() from java code just sends a close request to OS. but OS which will actually manages socket. The same code is working fine with Linux Server, only Windows server has this issue. After socket.close(), i can see state as "CLOSE_WAIT" using netstat command

Comment: "CLOSE_WAIT" means it is not free to be used for some other socket to open.

Comment: TcpTimedWaitDelay, etc this is windows registry setting i am using to close all TIME_WAIT sockets at OS layer. From code all the sockets are closed properly, also in exception case too

Comment: @RahulAgrawal `CLOSE_WAIT` means it is *waiting for the applicaton running in this host* to close the socket, which bears out what I said above. Don't just apply bandaids to this to staunch the bleeding: fix the *problem.*